# How can I make my android splash screen logo png's background transparent?

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I'm making an android app. In my drawable folders I have my BG files, logo files, and icon files. The logos are transparent pngs. However, when the app loads the splash screen the logos render the transparent part of the background black instead of transparent like I want. I've tried adding:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

In the splash_screen.xml file and the file currently looks like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="fill">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/logo" android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I was getting an error during build where the logs claimed some of the pngs were not pngs. I got around this by turning off png optimization in app.gradle. Here is the contents of the file with cruncherEnabled set to false:

```
android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "org.nativescript.AlertMeJS"  
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    cruncherEnabled = false
  }  
}
```

Maybe the two are related but the pngs seem valid and open fine in photoshop...

I'm pretty new to android development so any help is greatly appreciated - thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: What does your layout look like?  My bet is you're drawing this right on top of the background of your app... which is black.  I'd set the background of the Layout that this is embedded in to whatever color you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the entire platform, reinstalling and rebuilding. Now everything works as expected. I am a bit frustrated because I don't know why this worked but I'll consider the issue closed since the question I asked is resolved.